# Merge an Object that wen outside the datacontext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I have the following question:
It is easy to insert an oBject in database with a form.

1. Just create an object
2. link it to the fields in your from.
3. Post back to controller,
4. create a new datacontext and do datacontext.InsertOnSubmit(object)

.

```
public static void AddPage(string lang, Page page)
                {
                    using (var db = new CardReaderDataContext())
                    {
                        page.Lang = lang;
                        page.URL = UrlHelper.CreateValidSeoUrl(page.Name, "-");
                        db.Pages.InsertOnSubmit(page);
                        db.SubmitChanges();
                    }
                }
```

---

But if you want to update an object, it is a tedious job.
You do the same flow,

1. you get the object,
2. link it to your form,
3. post it, but THEN !!!
   because it went outside your datacontext, you have to reload the object from the datacontext,
4. transfer all the variables and save it, 
   this is a little complex explained so I give an example:

**To update an object that you modified in a form:**

```
public static void Update(Page page)
        {
            using (var db = new CardReaderDataContext())
            {
                var _page = db.Pages.Where(p => p.Guid == page.Guid).Single();
                _page.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
                _page.Title = page.Title;
                _page.Description = page.Description;
                _page.Content = page.Content;
                _page.Keywords = page.Keywords;
                _page.Name = page.Name;
                _page.WTLang = page.WTLang;
                _page.WTSKU = page.WTSKU;
                _page.WTTi = page.WTTi;
                _page.WTUri = page.WTUri;
                _page.URL = UrlHelper.CreateValidSeoUrl(page.Name, "-");
                //  _page.Order = GetMaxOrderByMenuGuid(page.MenuGuid);
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
```

I don't know if it is clear, if it isn't comment me, I will edit

Comment: Is it Linq-to-SQL you are using? And what exactly is your question, btw?

Comment: yes linq-to-sql, my question is, is there an easier way to merge those objects on update, instead of, for each value, copying the new value to the object retrieved from the db. now what you do is: retrieve the object from db, modifie values, retrieve the same object, store every value to the last retrieved one, update

Comment: hmmm is my question not clear or is there just no answer to this

Comment: As far as I know, that's the way it is done in L2S. (In Entity Framework you can play around with the EntityState to avoid re-querying the database.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for DataContext.Attach, but you can only use that with linqtosql objects that have been serialised/deserialised.

Have a read of the answer to this question - 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/384a1c03-3acf-43ef-9a25-b84f93025e63/

> "It's also not a good idea to even
>   attempt to fetch the old version.  By
>   doing that you are in effect turning
>   off optimistic concurrency, so unless
>   you intended that this is a bad
>   approach.  What you need to do is
>   round trip both the original state and
>   the current state of the object."

Comment: this is not really a global solution answer (I don't think there is one), but the link you provided and the ones that are present in that one are more then helpfull, and give me good insight on the question